# Get data from two http req and combine them

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, schema

I have two schema in mongoose one for doctors info and two for ranking.
my doctors schema :

```
var doctorsSchema = new schema({
  Entity: {type:String},
  name: {type:String},
  Expertise : {type:String},
  HMO: {type:String},
  Address: {type:String},
  reception_hours: [],
  lat: {type:Number},
  lng: {type:Number},
  Ranking : {type:Number}
},{collection: 'doctorsLocation'});
```

my ranking schema is:

```
var calSchema = new schema({
  Entity: {type:String},
  name: {type:String},
  Expertise : {type:String},
  Address: {type:String},
  Attention : {type:Number},
  Professional: {type:Number},
  Availability: {type:Number},
  Atmosphere: {type:Number},
  Recommendation: {type:Number}
},{collection: 'cal'});
```

I want to calculate the ranking of each doctor and after to print all the details of each doctor to the screen.

this is my controller (in angularjs):

```
mymedical.controller('calCtrl',['$scope','$http','$cookies', function($scope,$http,$cookies){
var generalInfo = Array();

  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/doctors').then(function(response){
      //console.log(response);
      var generalData = response.data;

    for(var i=0; i<generalData.length; i++){
    $http.post('http://localhost:3000/calculateRanking',generalData).then(function(res){
            //console.log(res.data);
            var info ={};
            info.Ranking = res.data;
            //console.log(res.data);
            console.log("1");
            info.Entity = generalData[i].Entity;
            info.name = generalData[i].name;
            info.Expertise = generalData[i].Expertise;
            info.Address = generalData[i].Address;

            info.reception_hours=generalData[i].reception_hours;
            info.HMO=generalData[i].HMO;
            generalInfo.push(info);
        }).then(last(generalInfo));
    }

                  //info.Ranking = 0;
          //console.log(rank);


  });

function last(val)
{
  $scope.general = val;
    //console.log(generalInfo);
    console.log("last");
}


}]);
```

I send all to server side all doctors and then,
I have function that calculate the ranking in server side(node.js)
the function get calSchema and over according to each doctor calculate them the ranking and send back to client side (controller) the ranking.
After I get the ranking I want to display all my data to screen ,
but I have problem with sync of angular its print me all doctors and after print me the ranking, and I want to print them together,
What I need to do to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: It looks like the entire array of doctors is being sent to the "calculateRanking" api. And it's happening for each doctor. Do you mean to just send one doctor at a time to it?

Comment: yes that exactly what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think this may be what you want

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/doctors').then(function(doctors) {
        angular.forEach(doctors.data, function(doctor) {
            $http.post('http://localhost:3000/calculateRanking', doctor)
                .then(function(res) {
                    doctor.Ranking = res.data;
                    $scope.general.push(doctor);
                });
        });
    });
```

So this will

1. Get all doctors
2. Loop through doctors
3. For each doctor, make an API call to get their ranking
4. Set the doctor's ranking
5. Push the doctor into the viewable array

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), might need a little tweaking. Hope it helps.

> helps you run functions asynchronously

```js
function postDocData(doc) {
  return $http
    .post('http://localhost:3000/calculateRanking', doc)
    .then(function(res) {
      doctor.Ranking = res.data;
      $scope.general.push(doctor);
    });
}

$http.get('http://localhost:3000/doctors').then(function(doctors) {
  var docPromiseArray = [];

  angular.forEach(doctors.data, function(doctor) {
    docPromiseArray.push(postDocData(doctor));
  });

  $q.all[docPromiseArray]
    .catch(function(err) {
      //error handling
      console.log(err);
    })
    .finally(function() {
      //more processing
    })
});
```